# Fn::Sub expression does not resolve to a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created a parameter:

```
Parameters:
  ..
  list:
    Description: "Provide a list .." 
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "test1, test2"
```

Now I want to reference this list (which will resolve in "test1", "test2", ..) from a file in my cloudformation which looks like this:

```
    configure_xx:
      files:        

        /etc/file.conf:
          content: !Sub |
            input {
              logs {
                log_group => [ "${list}" ]
                access_key_id => "${logstashUserKey}"
                secret_access_key => "${logstashUserKey.SecretAccessKey}"
                region => "eu-west-1"
                }
            }
```

How can I make this work for the parameter list? (the keys work).
error:  `Fn::Sub expression does not resolve to a string`

Answer (score 3):

Just switch the parameter type for a "String"

```
Parameters:
  ..
  list:
    Description: "Provide a list .." 
    Type: String
    Default: "test1, test2"
```

If, for some reason, you have no control over this parameter type, you could use `Fn::Join` to transform the list to a string. For exemple:

```
configure_xx:
  files:        

    /etc/file.conf:
      content: 
        Fn::Sub:
        - |-
            input {
              logs {
                log_group => [ "${joinedlist}" ]
                access_key_id => "${logstashUserKey}"
                secret_access_key => "${logstashUserKey.SecretAccessKey}"
                region => "eu-west-1"
                }
            }
        - joinedlist:
            Fn::Join:
            - ', '
            - !Ref list
```